# convertir jquery a JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

tengo estos dos partes de codigo en jquery y no se como convertirlo en JS:

```
$('#data > tbody:last').append(
'<tr class="warning">
   <td>' + nBet + '</td>
   <td>' + parseFloat(curBet * curRaise).toFixed(8) + '</td>
   <td colspan="6">Casino Broke Your Bank</td>
</tr>');
    
$("#summary").html(
   "Your strategy supports 
   <span class='warning'>" + (nBet - 1).toString() + "</span>
   Losses<p>A persistence of this strategy is <span class='warning'>" + 
   ((nBet - 1) / parseFloat($("#tx_payout").html())).toFixed(1) + 
   "</span> <span class='minrec'>(Higher is better)</span>");
```

```
$('#data > tbody:last').append('<tr class="warning"><td>' + nBet + '</td><td>' + parseFloat(curBet * curRaise).toFixed(8) + '</td><td colspan="6">Casino Broke Your Bank</td></tr>');
    $("#summary").html("Your strategy supports <span class='warning'>" + (nBet - 1).toString() + "</span> Losses<p>A persistence of this strategy 
is <span class='warning'>" + ((nBet - 1) / parseFloat
($("#tx_payout").html())).toFixed(1) + "</span> 
<span class='minrec'>(Higher is better)</span>");
```

he probado a usar convertidores online pero no han sabido darme un resultado.
Estoy aprendiendo JS y solo se que tiene a que ver con la manipulacion del DOM

Comment: los codigos mostrados son los mismos..

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar el API del DOM en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), especialmente los métodos `document.querySelector`, `document.querySelectorAll` y el atributo `element.innerHTML`.